# Glassfish 5 ignores JAXB @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, glassfish, jax-rs

I just switched to Glassfish 5 from Glassfish 4 and I noticed that Glassfish no longer called the unmarshal method of my DateTimeAdapter class, it worked okay in Glassfish 4. The Web service class receives a json data and it should be converted automatically to the appropriate RegisterItemDTO object. I've tried putting the annotation on the getter method and it still didn't work. The unmarshal method was never called. I've made sure the json data was in the right format.

Service class:

```
@Stateless
@Path("")
public class InventoryService 
{        
    @POST
    @Path("/incoming_goods")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) 
    public Response addIncomingGood(RegisterItemDTO _dto) throws Exception {

    // .....

    }
}
```

Object class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RegisterItemDTO
{    
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateTimeAdapter.class)
    private Date incomingDate;

    // ....  
    // I've tried putting the annotation on the getter method and it still didn't work
    // @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateTimeAdapter.class)
    // public Date getIncomingDate () {return incomingDate;}
}
```

Adapter class:

```
public class DateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date>
{
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 

    @Override 
    public Date unmarshal(String xml) throws Exception 
    { 
        try {
            System.out.println ("DATE FORMAT CALLED");  // this is never printed
            return dateFormat.parse(xml); 
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println ("Error: " + e.getMessage ());
            e.printStackTrace ();
            throw e;
        }
    } 

    // ..
}
```

Exception:

```
Info:   Exception Mapper: Error deserializing object from entity stream.
Severe:   javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jsonb.internal.JsonBindingProvider.readFrom(JsonBindingProvider.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:257)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1091)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Error parsing date from value: 2017-12-29 00:00:00
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractDateTimeDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDateTimeDeserializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractValueTypeDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractValueTypeDeserializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectDeserializer.deserializeNext(ObjectDeserializer.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserializeInternal(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserializeItem(Unmarshaller.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserialize(Unmarshaller.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.deserialize(JsonBinding.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.fromJson(JsonBinding.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jsonb.internal.JsonBindingProvider.readFrom(JsonBindingProvider.java:99)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-12-29 00:00:00' could not be parsed at index 10
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1777)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.DateTypeDeserializer.parseDefault(DateTypeDeserializer.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.DateTypeDeserializer.parseDefault(DateTypeDeserializer.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractDateTimeDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDateTimeDeserializer.java:62)
    ... 69 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Glassfish 5 no longer uses MOXy as the default provider. Looking at the stack trace it looks like [JSON Binding](http://json-b.net), which for jersey, the provider is `jersey-media-json-binding`.

You can add the `jersey-media-moxy` or `jersey-media-json-jackson` to your project and register either the `MoxyJsonFeature` or `JacksonFeature`, respectively. Both will support the annotation. Make sure if you use one of those, get the latest version. And just a matter of opinion, I would chose the Jackson provider.